# Validation loss higher than training loss from first epoch

Tags: deep-learning, fast-ai

From what I’ve learned when the validation loss > training loss there is overfitting. However I’m getting this from the first epoch.

See below:

[image]

I'm using a tabular learner (from FastAI v2) that has about 72 inputs.

I have 360K unevenly distributed cases, of which the majority is cat1, then cat2, etc… We got about 20K of cat6. I upsample all training data so all categories are equally represented. The validation set is 2% of the training set.
I tried lowering the number of layers. This brings the training loss a bit closer to the validation loss, but the validation loss always is high than the training loss, from the first epoch on.

What could be the explanation for this?

Code used:

```
coord_labels, semantic_labels = [], []
for i in range(18):
    coord_labels += [f'x{i+1}', f'y{i+1}', f'conf{i+1}']
    semantic_labels += [f'sem{i+1}']
    
dls = TabularDataLoaders.from_csv(
    '/content/total_training.csv', 
    y_names='corrected_person_position_type_id',
    cont_names = coord_labels,
    cat_names = semantic_labels,
    procs = [Categorify, Normalize],
    valid_idx = valid_idx,
    bs=2048
)
learn = tabular_learner(dls, metrics=accuracy)
learn.fit_one_cycle(10)
```

Comment: Can you add validation accuracy in the table and some code as reference?

Comment: @ZabirAlNazi added code.  I was under the impression that the accuracy displayed from fastai tabular-learner is the validation accuracy.  If it's not, any idea on how to add this?